# Is there a way to propagate a compiler flag FROM a SUB_DIRECTORY to the whole project in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm currently running into a situation that I need to build my project with some 3rd-party libraries.
One of the 3rd-party library (say `libA`) is using `GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_API=0`, while other libraries using `1` (and `1` if preferred over `0` if both are ok, i.e. 3rd-party lib is provided with source). Those libraries are ***exclusive***, so this question is not about how to link different ABIs together.

Now it compiles, if I manually choose the ABI version carefully, along with which 3rd-party library I'm using, the command line will look like `cmake -DTHIRD_PARTY_LIB=LIBA -DUSE_NEW_ABI=OFF` or `cmake -DTHIRD_PARTY_LIB=LIB_ELSE -DUSE_NEW_ABI=ON`. But simply I don't want to provide the extra command line option `-DUSE_NEW_ABI`, because it can be inferred from which library is to be used.

If my project was just a simple project with no subprojects/subdirectories, everything would be simple enough: I can just check what `THIRD_PARTY_LIB` is in `CMakeLists.txt` and set the corresponding compiler definition. But in real world, I need to propagate the flag globally.

Let's say I have top-level projects `T1, T2, T3`, libraries `L4, L5, L6, L_USE_3rd`, each in a separate directory. `L_USE_3rd` is the exact library directly uses a 3rd-party library mentioned above, so **I want to put the logic of deciding ABI according to which lib being used inside the project directly uses it, and spread it project-wide**.

Passing it to `T1, T2, T3` is easy as long as it links to `L_USE_3rd`, `target_add_*()` will do the job perfectly. But it seems impossible to pass it to `L4, L5, L6`, which does not depends on `L_USE_3rd`.

I know a solution by **putting and duplicating the logic in `T1, T2, T3`**, but this simply makes it hard to maintain if the 3rd-party lib list is to change in the future. So is there a way to propagate the compiler flag from a subdirectory globally?

Comment: So what is wrong with `target_compile_definitions(L_USE_3rd PUBLIC GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_API=0)`?

Comment: @KamilCuk **But it seems impossible to pass it to L4, L5, L6, which does not depends on L_USE_3rd.**

Comment: So make them depend on it.

Comment: then what if L_USE_3rd also depends on L4

Comment: ? What if? Static libraries allow cyclic dependencies.

Comment: it's not any static lib cyclic dependency issue. it's `L4` should not even be aware of the existence of `L_USE_3rd`. Adding redundant checks (to link to `L_USE_3rd` if such target is present, do nothing if not) in `L4` , and maybe in `L5` `L6` `L7` ... 's `CMakeLists.txt` only makes the situation more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It's typical to provide a file with some global setup that needs to be done. Like this:

```
#  third_party/third_party_lib.cmake
include_guard()
function(third_party_setup)
    add_definitions(GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_API=0)
endfunction()

# user cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
include(third_party/third_party_lib.cmake)
third_party_setup() # sets definitions
project(your_project)
add_library(libs ...)
```

[Zephyr](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/application/index.html) for example did `include($ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE}/cmake/app/boilerplate.cmake NO_POLICY_SCOPE)` to setup some variables and now they provide the same via handy `find_package(Zephyr)` interface.